# Oracle sql developer does not start in fedora 20

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, fedora, fedora20

I am download last version of Oracle sql developer RPM version from oracle website and install it on my fedora 20 , after running sql developer , program does not start with following result:

```
[mohsen@localhost bin]$ sqldeveloper 

 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.



 LOAD TIME : 655#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3d8abb5910, pid=18459, tid=139904211367680
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C[thread 139904223835904 also had an error]
  0x00007f3d8abb5910
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid18459.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/../../ide/bin/launcher.sh: line 1193: 18459 Aborted                 (core dumped) ${JAVA} "${APP_VM_OPTS[@]}" ${APP_ENV_VARS} -classpath ${APP_CLASSPATH} ${APP_MAIN_CLASS} "${APP_APP_OPTS[@]}"
```

I am using sqldeveloper 4.0.3.16 java 7u67 on fedora 20

Comment: Presume that `Java Home` has been set.

Comment: the JAVA_HOME is setted